# terminal find file with latest patch number

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a folder with a lot of patch files with pattern

```
1.1.hotfix1
1.2.hotfix2 
2.1.hotfix1
2.1.hotfix2 ...etc
```

and I have to find out the latest patch(`2.1.hotfix2` should be the result of the example) with a bash

how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse order all files by time and print the first line.

In case you have some other files then you can print files having hotfix text only.

```
ls -t1 *hotfix* |  head -n 1
```

Comment: is it possible to find it out without using the modified time? because sometimes I'm not sure if it must be the last modified one

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` with regex, and take the last line from `sort`:

```
find * -type f -regex "^[^\d]+\.[^\d]+\.hotfix[^\d]+$" | sort | tail -1
```